# how to capture trap message in net-snmp

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

i work with net-snmp and i try a few commands like:

```
 snmptrap -v 1 -c public host TRAP-TEST-MIB::demotraps localhost 6 17 '' \
    SNMPv2-MIB::sysLocation.0 s "Just here"

 snmptrap -v 2c -c public localhost '' NOTIFICATION-TEST-MIB::demo-notif \
    SNMPv2-MIB::sysLocation.0 s "just here"


snmptrap -v 1 -c public host NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB::netSnmpExampleHeartbeatNotification "" 6 17 "" \
       netSnmpExampleHeartbeatRate i 123456
```

but is just give me a new line without error or something
someone can give me advice ?

Comment: Do you have any indication that the command is not working as expected? snmptrap does not output anything on success (following the regular Unix convention).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netsnmp provides [Snmptrapd](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Snmptrapd) for this purpose.

It is an application which can listen on a port (default 162) on a host for traps and will log those that are received.

//EDIT ...

Here is an example ...

```
snmptrapd -f -m +ALL -Lo  -c /tmp/snmptrapd.conf 9876
```

where `/tmp/snmptrapd.conf` only contains one line which for simplicity disables community/password checking

```
disableAuthorization yes
```

Use  `man snmptrapd` to see what the flags/arguements mean.

Comment: Examples:

To get a message like "14:03 TRAP3.1 from humpty.ucd.edu" you could use something like this:

snmptrapd -P -F "%02.2h:%02.2j TRAP%w.%q from %A\n"
If you want the same thing but in GMT rather than local time, use

snmptrapd -P -F "%#02.2h:%#02.2j TRAP%w.%q from %A\n"

Comment: this is what you mean?

Comment: This tool belongs to net-snmp ?

Comment: Yes, it is part of the net-snmp suite. I have added an example to my answer.

Comment: "where /tmp/snmptrapd.conf only contains one line which for simplicity disables community/password checking"    you mean to community string?

Comment: Yes authCommunity plus others. See http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmptrapd.conf.html  ; disableAuthorization yes = 
    will disable the above access control checks, and revert to the previous behaviour of accepting all incoming notifications.